# How to handle mismatch between VR headset FOV and video stream FOV?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, gear-vr, 360-virtual-reality

This question is based on my previous [question about the difference between ViewPort and FOV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39971537/what-is-the-difference-between-viewport-and-field-of-view-fov-in-vr-devices/39999088?noredirect=1#comment67312760_39999088).

I'm writing an application which receives 360-video and renders on screen.

Assume my video stream contains some information about the dimension of FOV (part of the video frame to be displayed at an instance) for each eye.

1. Do I need to render that FOV within the ViewPort of each eye?
2. I saw that some VR headsets advertise about their FOV. So, I think sometimes the device FOV may be different than video stream FOV. In those cases, filling the entire ViewPort by stream FOV might degrade the viewing experience. I think application may choose either different FOV or ViewPort (Filling black around the new ViewPort if required) to handle such cases. What is the recommended solution to this problem?